# Pinch and zoom behaviour for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to create a behavior for Pinch and zoom to Image control in windows phone 8. I am trying to apply pinch and zoom along with rotation to Image in my application. In a forum I found that Gesture listener is deprecated and they are not promoting implementation with gesture. So can any one please suggest an alternative method for me.

Comment: I found the perfect soultion for pinch to zoom and pan. It is actually a Microsoft Code sample at the following link
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Image-Recipes-0c0b8fee I just used it as boiler plate code and it worked wonders. Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're targeting only Windows Phone 8 you can use the new [ManipulationDeltaEventArgs.PinchManipulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.input.manipulationdeltaeventargs.pinchmanipulation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property from the ManipulationDelta event. Instead of using GestureListener/TouchPanel for pinch & zoom you should rely on this new property.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969400/pinch-to-zoom-functionality-in-windows-phone-8?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you https://multitouch.codeplex.com/

```
Windows Phone / Silverlight Behaviors and WPF samples implementing Multi-Touch Manipulation (Gestures) and Inertia.
```

Comment: Please find this issue in discussion forum https://multitouch.codeplex.com/discussions/405530