# How to add zooming facility like native video capturing in app for window phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, video-capture, zooming

I am developing the customize video capture app. In that I am using AudioVideoCaptureDevice to record the video. Like a Native video capturing I want to add zooming in the video recording. In native video recording one can zoom the screen only before starting the capturing, I need the same behavior. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programmatically zooming the AudioVideoCaptureDevice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467117/programmatically-zooming-the-audiovideocapturedevice)

Comment: I don't know why the answer is accepted in the post you have suggested as the code given & sample suggested not zooming the camera view at all. I need pinch zooming, though the canvas I can zoom in/out but the recording is happening without affecting with zoom. I think there should be a way through AudioVideoCaptureDevice directly but couldn't find the solution.