# blend ZoomMode in scrollviewer for windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, zooming, scrollview, expression-blend

I have a scrollviewer where i want to integrate a zoom function. By searching on the internet I have found that there exists a function called:

"ScrollViewer.ZoomMode"

Where as I understand should enable zoom property to your list and everything within. But I do not have this property in my code. Do someone know if you need to add some reference that is not there?

**EDIT**
Okay, Thank you. But I have looked at this but not been able to get it to work, as I want :) I want to have a list of elements(text, button & image), that can be manipulated by scrolling and zoom. Is there a smart way to do this? like integrating the list with a viewbox?

**Second EDIT**
I can only upload alot of xaml, since it is done through blend. Where I have, lets say a map with different buttons. I have implemented scroll for all directions using scrollviewer. But I also wanted to be able to zoom. I have tried different ways, like viewbox and with some c#. But with little success. So I can share the code but is is only created by blend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZoomMode is not available on the Windows Phone platform.

ZoomMode is a property on the ScrollViewer when developing Windows Store App's, not for phone.

Zoom however can still implemented, just not as a part of the ScrollViewer. 
Here a post on creating pinch zooming on a image:
[Pinch To Zoom functionality in windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969400/pinch-to-zoom-functionality-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: Okay, Thank you.
But I have looked at this but not been able to get it to work, as I want :) I want to have a list of elements(text, button & image), that can be manipulated by scrolling and zoom. Is there a smart way to do this? like integrating the list with a viewbox?

Comment: It's really hard to answer a question like that without seeing it. My guess is it's not easy to do, but it's definitely doable. Try describing what you want, and possible share more code, the project, or some images so the community has a chance of seeing what you are trying achieve, and then can try to help you out.

Comment: I can add some code but it would only be from a blend where scroll viewer has been enabled to work for all directions. What I want to do is the same as what happens on your mobile when looking on a browser that you can scroll around and zoom, and the content with buttons also changes size.